# Trouble importing Highcharts Gauge with NPM/Webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, highcharts

I have HighCharts inside a website using vanilla JS, I use webpack/npm to load and import modules. I am able to use the Spline and Column charts just fine. I tried adding the standard Gauge chart ([shown here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer)), and received the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=gauge
```

When searching for the module in the `node_modules/highcarts/modules` folder, I cannot find it.

Here is how I am importing HighCharts:

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
```

Here is how I am calling the chart:

```
 $('#speedometerContainer').highcharts({
     chart: {
         type: 'gauge',
         plotBackgroundColor: null,
         plotBackgroundImage: null,
         plotBorderWidth: 0,
           plotShadow: false
     },...
```

This is working for both column and spline chart types.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to import `highcharts-more`, which contained the Gauge I needed.

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
```